# Hexagon Rearrangement Problem (How many ways to rearrange these hexagons so that every pair of adjacent hexagons become non-adjacent?)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, combinations

Here is the detail:
There are $\displaystyle \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ ($n$ layers) hexagons forming a triangle. Denote them as $H_i$ from top to bottom and from left to right. Now I want to find the number of ways to rearrange them so that every pair of adjacent hexagon become non-adjacent.

For example, when $n=4$, one of the feasible arrangement is like https://s1.ax1x.com/2020/08/18/dMw4yR.png
, and I can find that there are 18 ways to do this by enumerating. For $n>4$, I don't know what to do. I would appreciate it if someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Interesting problem.  Where does it come from?

Comment: @saulspatz It comes from my cousin's exam paper, originally it's about bee hives.

Comment: That's surprising.  Do you happen to know what course your cousin was taking?

Comment: @saulspatz I'm not sure, but as far as I know it's about preparing for some province-wide math competition for senior high school students. And their main course is just called "math" involving primary combinatorics and graph-theory (etc.).

Comment: *When n=4, ...I can find that there are 18 ways to do this by enumerating. For n>4, I don't know what to do.* The obvious suggestion is to use the same method. Is there any reason why you think this will not work?

Comment: @sammygerbil because for n>4, it would be painful to enumerate, and I wish there can be some general formula or some efficient algorithm to descript the result.